# Translating POST request from Java to Python - fail to POST data

Tags: java, python, http-post

I came around with a situation where I need to translate an apparently simple Java code to Python.

The Java code is just making a `POST` request to a URL with three params. The code is bellow:

```
{
 java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
 String content = "phonenr=" + smsPhone + "&smstxt=" + smsMessage + "&Submit=SendSms";

 java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(smsGatewayPath);
 java.net.HttpURLConnection urlCon = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

 urlCon.setReadTimeout(5000);
 urlCon.setDoInput(true);
 urlCon.setDoOutput(true);
 urlCon.setUseCaches(false);
 urlCon.setRequestMethod("POST");

 urlCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(content.length()));
 urlCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
 urlCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEncoded);

 java.io.DataOutputStream output = new java.io.DataOutputStream(urlCon.getOutputStream());

 output.writeBytes(content);

 output.flush();
 output.close();

 java.io.DataInputStream input = new java.io.DataInputStream(urlCon.getInputStream());

 int bufSize = 4096;
 byte[] bytesRead = new byte[bufSize];
 int bytesReadLength = 0;

 while ((bytesReadLength = input.read(bytesRead)) > 0) {
  baos.write(bytesRead, 0, bytesReadLength);
 }

 input.close();
 baos.close();

 return org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(baos.toString("UTF-8"));

}
```

Now, I tried to make the same request in Python, to POST the exact same data to the same URL:

```
import requests

SMS_BOX_URL = 'http://ip/name.cgi'

USER = "admin"
PASS = "password"

auth_string_encoded = "YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ="

headers = {"Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8", "Authorization": "Basic %s" % auth_string_encoded}

content = {'phonenr': 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'smstext': 'Test', 'Submit': 'SendSms'}
req_post = requests.post(SMS_BOX_URL, data=content, auth=(USER,PASS), headers=headers)

print(req_post.text)
print(req_post.url)
print(req_post.status_code)
```

Now, the output that I get from this is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TopexGateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#00CCFF" text="#000000">
ERROR
</body>
</html>

http://ip/name.cgi
200
```

Now I am a little confused why this is not working because when I make a CURL request everything seems to work:

```
curl -v --data "phonenr=xxxxx&smstxt=Test&Submit=SendSms" http://admin:password@ip/name.cgi
```

[Here](https://dpaste.de/7Nwc) is a paste from what I receive with CURL and [here](https://dpaste.de/Nz6k) what I receive with Python.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my python version ?

Comment: Your curl command doesn't have headers, so it's not exactly the same in your python script. Did you try without headers?

Comment: @Ioutre Yes, I tried. The same output though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Java:   "smstxt"
Python: "smstext"
```

That letter `e`: invisible to humans, all the difference to computers.

Comment: I'll someday buy you that beer ^^ Thanks man. Three days for one letter !